# Swing - last JMenuItem occupy the rest of space on JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I find that if I have a `JMenuBar`, and the last element of it (the rightmost one) is a `JMenuItem`, it will occupy all the rest blank space on the JMenuBar, which is definitely not what we want.

Imagine an "About" JMenuItem as the rightmost item on a JMenuBar. It should only occupy the same space as the other menus.

See my SSCCE: (click the menu and hover over the menuitem on the right to see the effect)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JMenuItemLastOnMenuBar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu 1");
        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        menu.add(item1);
        bar.add(menu);

        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2") {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(120, 25);
            }
        };
        bar.add(item2);

        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: **Why** is the code overriding the preferred size of `item2`?

Comment: You should add a separator/spacer to the end...

Comment: @AndrewThompson because I want to make it always return a proper preferredsize for layout manager to use. Or something else.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto The idea is interesting but this does not work. I tried and the rest blank space is cutted into two halves, with JMenuItem occupying the first/left half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the method `getMaximumSize`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JMenuItemLastOnMenuBar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu 1");
        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        menu.add(item1);
        bar.add(menu);

        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2") {
            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                Dimension d1 = super.getPreferredSize();
                Dimension d2 = super.getMaximumSize();
                d2.width = d1.width;
                return d2;
            }
        };
        bar.add(item2);

        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: This works. Now the JMenuItem is much smaller and controllable, thanks! Now it is irrelevant but why the JMenuItem on the JMenuBar has no hover-over animation?

Comment: @FaithReaper it's not implemented in the L&F you use. Some L&F supports hover animation (try to [set the Windows L&F](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)).

Comment: @SergiyMendvynskyy I have checked but it is not working. Hover animation is shown only after I click on the menu and hover onto the JMenuItem in the menu once. If I close the menu, the second item has no animation.

Comment: `JMenuItem`'s are usually not visible until the menu they belong is clicked. This may be the cause of the way hovering is handled...

Comment: Hm. I think so, too. Weird, though: it is common to have a JMenuItem in a JMenubar. It is legit, at least. Swing is buggy.